# Most Efficient Method to Concatenate Strings in Python

Tags: python, string, performance

At the time of asking this question, I'm using **Python 3.8**

When I say efficient, I'm only referring to the speed at which the strings are concatenated, or in more technical terms: I'm asking about the time complexity, not accounting the space complexity.

The only methods I can think of at the moment are the following 3 given that:

```
a = 'start'
b = ' end'
```

**Method 1**

`result = a + b`

**Method 2**

`result = ''.join((a, b))`

**Method 3**

`result = '{0}{1}'.format(a, b)`

I want to know which of these methods are faster, or if there are other methods that are more efficient. Also, if you know if either of these methods performs differently with more strings or longer strings, please include that in your answer.

**Edit**

After seeing all the comments and answers, I have learned a couple of new ways to concatenate strings, and I have also learned about the *timeit* library. I will report my personal findings below:

```
>>> import timeit

>>> print(timeit.Timer('result = a + b', setup='a = "start"; b = " end"').timeit(number=10000))
0.0005306000000473432

>>> print(timeit.Timer('result = "".join((a, b))', setup='a = "start"; b = " end"').timeit(number=10000))
0.0011297000000354274

>>> print(timeit.Timer('result = "{0}{1}".format(a, b)', setup='a = "start"; b = " end"').timeit(number=10000))
0.002327799999989111

>>> print(timeit.Timer('result = f"{a}{b}"', setup='a = "start"; b = " end"').timeit(number=10000))
0.0005772000000092703

>>> print(timeit.Timer('result = "%s%s" % (a, b)', setup='a = "start"; b = " end"').timeit(number=10000))
0.0017815999999584164
```

It seems that for these small strings, the traditional `a + b` method is the fastest for string concatenation. Thanks for all of the answers!

Comment: use timeit or horology to get a measure!

Comment: You should profile different methods and report back your findings to help others.

Comment: see if theres a time difference between method 3 and f"{a}{b}" too

Comment: Note that any time tests you might perform are sensitive to the lengths of each string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's try it out! We can use [timeit.timeit()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit) to run a statement many times and return the overall duration.

Here, we use `s` to setup the variables `a` and `b` (not included in the overall time), and then run the various options 10 million times.

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>>
>>> n = 10 * 1000 * 1000
>>> s = "a = 'start'; b = ' end'"
>>>
>>> timeit("c = a + b",                 setup=s, number=n)
0.4452877212315798
>>>
>>> timeit("c = f'{a}{b}'",             setup=s, number=n)
0.5252049304544926
>>>
>>> timeit("c = '%s%s'.format(a, b)",   setup=s, number=n)
0.6849184390157461
>>>>
>>> timeit("c = ''.join((a, b))",       setup=s, number=n)
0.8546998891979456
>>>
>>> timeit("c = '%s%s' % (a, b)",       setup=s, number=n)
1.1699129864573479
>>>
>>> timeit("c = '{0}{1}'.format(a, b)", setup=s, number=n)
1.5954962372779846
```

This shows that unless your application's bottleneck is string concatenation, it's probably not worth being too concerned about...

- The best case is ~0.45 seconds for 10 million iterations, or about 45ns per operation.
- The worst case is ~1.59 seconds for 10 million iterations, or about 159ns per operation.

Depending on the performance of your system, you might see a speed improvement in the order of a few seconds if you're performing ***literally millions*** of operations.

Note that your results may vary quite drastically depending on the lengths (and number) of the strings you're concatenating, and the hardware you're running on.

Answer (score 6):

For exactly two strings `a` and `b`, just use `a + b`. The alternatives are for joining *more* than 2 strings, avoiding the temporary `str` object created by each use of `+`, as well as the quadratic behavior due to repeatedly copying the contents of earlier operations in the next result.

(There's also `f'{a}{b}'`, but it's syntactically  heavier and no faster than `a + b`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
a = "start"
b = " end"

start = datetime.now()
print(a+b)
print(datetime.now() - start)

start = datetime.now()
print("".join((a, b)))
print(datetime.now() - start)

start = datetime.now()
print('{0}{1}'.format(a, b))
print(datetime.now() - start)

# Output
# start end
# 0:00:00.000056
# start end
# 0:00:00.000014
# start end
# 0:00:00.000014
```

Looks like .join() and .format() are basically the same and 4x faster. An F string, eg:

```
print(f'{a} {b}')
```

is also a very quick and clean method, especially when working with more complex formats.

Comment: Be careful! Performing the operation only once will introduce unnecessary noise - for example, you'll probaly find that most of your time here is spent in the back of `datetime.now()`, `print()` and the front of `datetime.now()`, rather than the string concatenation that you intended to measure (approx nanoseconds, vs the microseconds you're reporting). `.join()` and `.format()` are _not_ faster than `+`.